# Setting nested Dictionary in Python: Why class method behaves differently from an standalone function?

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider this simplified class:

```
class test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_dict = {}

    def nested_set_method(self, keys,value=None):
        end = len(keys) - 1
        for index, component in enumerate(keys):
            if index < end or value is None:
                self.inner_dict = self.inner_dict.setdefault(component, {})
            else:
                self.inner_dict[component] = value
```

and this function which is identical to `nested_set_method` of the above class:

```
def nested_set_standalone(input_dict, keys,value=None):
    end = len(keys) - 1
    for index, component in enumerate(keys):
        if index < end or value is None:
            input_dict = input_dict.setdefault(component, {})
        else:
            input_dict[component] = value
```

This is a sample usage of the class:

```
>>> a = test()
>>> a.inner_dict
{}
>>> a.nested_set_method([1,2,3,4],'l')
>>> a.inner_dict
{4: 'l'}
```

This is the sample usage of the function over an instance of the class:

```
>>> b = test()
>>> b.inner_dict
{}
>>> nested_set_standalone(b.inner_dict,[1,2,3,4],'l')
>>> b.inner_dict
{1: {2: {3: {4: 'l'}}}}
```

I expected the class's `nested_set_method` with this output `{4: 'l'}` to have the same output as the function `nested_set_standalone` which is `{1: {2: {3: {4: 'l'}}}}`.

But why are they different?

EDIT: I ran these examples on Python 3.6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inner_dict` in the function is a local variable, but in the method it changes the attribute. Simply, use a local variable, too:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inner_dict = {}

    def get_nested_dict(self, keys):
        inner_dict = self.inner_dict
        for component in keys:
            inner_dict = inner_dict.setdefault(component, {})
        return inner_dict

    def nested_set_method(self, keys,value=None):
        if value is None:
            return self.get_nested_dict(keys)
        else:
            inner_dict = self.get_nested_dict(keys[:-1])
            inner_dict[keys[-1]] = value
```

Comment: This actually solves the issue, but aren't we directly changing the `input_dict` in the function as well? why isn't that affecting the input? (this line: `input_dict = input_dict.setdefault(component, {})`)

Comment: You're changing the value of `input_dict` in the `nested_set_standalone` function, but `b.inner_dict` is not changed and still refers to the original `b.inner_dict`, though it has a key added to it. It's only the local `input_dict` pointer that's changed.